# Post HttpClient returns either body was null or body was object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

Trying to use HttpClient to post data I get two different errors:

1. With `booking` being an object I get `Backend returned code 400, body was: [object Object]`.
2. Using `JSON.stringify(booking)` I get `Backend returned code 415, body was: null`.

How so?

```
public addBooking(booking): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.post<any[]>(`${this.url}bookings`, booking)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

**Object:**
Using the following as a test object in swagger works.

```
{
  "firstDate": "2020-05-29",
  "secondDate": "2020-05-29",
  "productId": 0,
  "userId": 0
}
```

Comment: what does your backend expect?

Comment: As it's the 4XX error, it means you're sending data that the server does not understand. first, you'll need to check out your back-end code to see what's the expected data type.

Comment: Can you console 'booking' and provide the data which is logged ?

Comment: @GauriKesavaKumar It either returns a correct object or the JSON version

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the "booking" data which you're sending it via POST request

Comment: @MohammadKermani Please see edit.

Comment: You have mentioned the swagger test execution input, but not the actual data you are sending to the API.

Comment: @GauriKesavaKumar The example value is the object I'm sending the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers.

```
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

public addBooking(booking): Observable<any[]> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  return this.http.post<any[]>(`${this.url}bookings`, booking, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

It seems, you data is not valid, because 400 is Bad Request. Also, your server respond with the error with `[Object object]` so I suggest you have to use smth like `JSON.stringify` on your server to respond with correct errors text

Answer (score 0):

Either the problem is because you have no set the 'Content-Type' in headers as 'application/json'. Otherwise, the problem might be because 'booking' is not actually JSON which contains the mentioned data.

*Note: Please mention the data which you are sending to the API (along with the response)*